# How to replace a monitor proprietary DC connector?

Tags: soldering, hardware

My Samsung S23700D (120Hz / 3D PC Monitor; 14V / 4A) has a loose DC connector, which caused the monitor to randomly turn off. After a lot of tinkering, the middle part of it broke : in short, I have to replace the DC connector. The problem is that I can't find a replacement online nor desolder the connector.

- My idea is to directly solder on the board one end of a DC (2.5mmx5.5mm) cable, as well as replace the original male DC plug of the power source.
- My soldering iron (48W), even at max power, damages the plastic but doesn't remove the solder on the board. I don't have much practice with soldering, but the solder I usually use (tin-based) easily melts. I also thought about breaking the connector, as a last resort.

How should I proceed? All suggestions are welcome.

Note that the DC connector has a 6.1mm OD with pin center, based on the male plug. It seems to be a proprietary format.

[image: Monitor board]

The original DC plug and the parts I intend to use:
[image: DC plugs]

Comment: This may seem counter-intuitive, but if you're having trouble melting the solder - add more. It provides a greater surface area of contact between the iron and the joint and, if there is some odd alloy being used it will help to 'mix' your solder with that to help it melt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting that kind of connector out is very hard with a soldering iron, as you need to heat all the terminals at the same time.  You'd be much better off with hot air.  A hot air soldering station would be good, but the kind of hot air gun used to strip paint would also work.  Use aluminium kitchen foil to protect nearby parts.

If you can't get the old connector off, it would be OK to solder a cable to the pins on the back and use that instead.  You might have to drill a small hole in the TV case to get the cable out, if the connector blocks the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the entire connector out at once with a normal iron will be very difficult.  Ideally you would use a suction tool to first remove as much solder from the holes and then try to work it out, but a high power iron is better for this.  Breaking the connector so you only have to remove one pin at a time is an option since you don't need the connector any longer, just be careful not to damage the board.  Desolder braid should also help you remove solder from the holes and clean up the pads after you remove the old part.

Another thing you could try is Chip-quik low temperature solder.  You would remove as much of the existing solder and add some of the low-temp solder.  It will stay liquid for longer so you have more time to heat all the pads, and then you should be able to remove the connector.  Once you do, be sure to remove as much as possible of the low temp solder before putting in the new connector and apply normal solder.